# Making Android builds with Unity 2018 beta

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have installed SDK JDK and added them as external tools in Unity everything looks right on paper, but when I try building it fails.

I have avdmanager in the location it's looking for it, so I'm completely puzzled. Help please!

I get the following error in console:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. 
/Users/mickeycreative/sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager list target -c

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.parseSdk(AvdManagerCli.java:328)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:204)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:195)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 6 more
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunAndroidSdkTool (System.String toolName, System.String arguments, Boolean updateCommand, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.ListTargetPlatforms (UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.GetTopAndroidPlatformAvailable (UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKPlatformDetector.GetVersion (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools sdkTools)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector.Detect (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools sdkTools, System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.ProgressHandler onProgress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.EnsureSDKComponentVersion (System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.SDKComponentDetector detector)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.EnsureSDKComponentVersion (Int32 minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.SDKComponentDetector detector)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled a lot with this one and found a solution.

Problem: The main reason why you get this failure is because the Android Tools invoked by Unity are not compatible with Java 9+. Pointing to a Java 8 JDK in the the Unity Preferences (External Tools) is not enough if your global JAVA_HOME is still pointing to a Java 9+ version.

Solution: Change the global JAVA_HOME to point to a JDK 8 VM (if you don't need Java 9 or 10 you can alternatively get rid of them so your system relies on Java 8 only)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and solved it by using older sdk versions. Maybe this will help :)

Comment: for reference, don't use jdk 9, use the older 1.8.x https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-builds-fail-with-java-9-jdk-and-unable-to-list-target-platforms-error